# Site not detecting index

Tags: .htaccess, httpd.conf, apache2.4, directoryindex, mod-dir

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04.2 Apache 2.4.7

I have a Virtual host set up to serve files from `/var/www/dev` and the config file looks like this for `dev.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ubuntu@12.234.567.89
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev
    ServerName dev.site.com

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/dev/>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a number of files in the `/var/www/dev` directory that I don't want indexed hence the `-Indexes` option

However I have a wordpress installation here too and I want those files to be served into a browser properly. The index file is `index.php` and is located in `/var/www/dev/`

I also have an .htaccess file in this same document root that looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/terms-and-conditions\.php$ /terms-of-use
RedirectMatch 301 ^/privacy\.php$ /privacy-policy
</IfModule>
```

The `DirectoryIndex` should tell the browser to use the `index.php` file, but I am getting a 403 Forbidden error.

I've tried:

- Opening up permissions, recursively changing ownership of `/var/www/dev` to `www-data:www-data`
- Adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` to the `dev.conf` file within the `<Directory /var/www/dev/>` tag - above and below the Options item
- Checking `mod_dir` is active (it is)
- Changing the indexes option back to `+Indexes` - when I load my site it displays the physical file index
- refreshing browser when I'm given the 403 or directory index will load my page correctly
- Clearing the browser cache every time I test in the browser
- Looked in my `apache2.conf` file and can confirm there is no other reference to `DirectoryIndex`
- Removing all references to DirectoryIndex and changing option to +Indexes - this makes everything work OK except users can see the directory index for all folders including the ones I don't want them to access

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:
Using chrome and firefox dev tools - if I click the option for Disable Cache (when dev tools are open) - the site loads fine - perhaps this is a clue

EDIT 2:
error.log outputs this line-

```
AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/dev/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

access.log just shows my browser details -

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1462 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
```

Comment: What does it say in apache access/error logs?

Comment: added my log outputs in an edit there

Comment: The error log says it, "No matching DirectoryIndex found". This means, it is not there, or overridden by another directive.

Comment: Thanks Olaf - this is what I've been investigating. The DirectoryIndex is there, it's the first line of my htaccess (above). I've checked dev.conf and the DirectoryIndex is not set here. It is set in mods-enabled/dir.conf correctly. What else could be overriding it? anywhere else to look?

Comment: This sounds all good, have you also loaded the module? Is there a `mods-enabled/dir.load`?

Comment: yes - dir.load is there

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry.